# React native align icon and text

Tags: react-native, flexbox

for the love of God, every styling i put on the stylesheet doesn't change anything.

i tried style the view, sectionheader & sectionbox but no luck

i want to align 4 icons in the boxsection and text below then as such, please any help would be appreciated.

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

```
 export default class HomePage extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View> 

            <SectionHeader title={'Food'} />
            <View >
             <SectionBox >
              <Icon style={styles.icons} name="icon name"  size={50} />
              <Icon style={styles.icons} name="icon name"  size={50} />
              <Icon style={styles.icons} name="icon name"  size={50} />
              <Icon style={styles.icons} name="icon name"  size={50} />

                <Text style={styles.sectiontext}>burgers</Text>
              </SectionBox>
            </View>

        const styles = StyleSheet.create({
          icons: {
            flexDirection: 'row',
            paddingTop: 7,
            paddingLeft: 5,



          },
          sectiontext: {
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            paddingLeft: 5,
            alignItems: 'center',
          }


        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the icons-containing-box you would need to indicate flexDirection and flexWrap, not directly on the icon's style.  Then to get the text below each icon you need to wrap icon and text in its own view and give that 'column' direction.

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

const ICON_SIZE = 70;
const FONT_SIZE = 18;

const getItem = () => (
  <View style={styles.iconStyle}>
    <Ionicons name="md-checkmark-circle" size={ICON_SIZE} color="green" />
    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>name</Text>
  </View>
);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.iconContainer}>
          {getItem()}
          {getItem()}
          {getItem()}
          {getItem()}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  iconContainer: {
    width: ICON_SIZE * 2,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
  iconStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    padding: 5,
  },
  textStyle: {
    fontSize: FONT_SIZE,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a view for each group of icon and text with a `flexDirection: 'column'` and one another view for each row (or column), like the example below:

https://snack.expo.io/HJY7IWsFm

Other option is to use a GridView lib:

https://github.com/saleel/react-native-super-grid